# How to make your iPhone beep every hour?

Tags: iphone, clock

Is it possible to have my iPhone making a sound every hour ? And preferably during day time, like 12 hours a day, and moreover only during weekdays only ?

Comment: For what reason exactly?

Comment: The irony is that the most modern, advanced smartphone can't simply do what an LCD watch from the 80's could do

Comment: @BradleyThomas True, but look at it from the perspective of iOS designers. If even 5% of students carrying iPhones set up an hourly chime, their instructors would loudly curse their devices—and the maker of their devices. That's not exactly publicity Apple strives for. It's already bad enough with people omitting to silence their phones before meetings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well – you can either set up returning alarms – but I suppose you already came up with that idea yourself. Or you can use one of those many many apps for hourly chimes. This overview claims to have a list of over 50 apps doing just that (and more) [www.appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-hourly-chimes](http://www.appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-hourly-chimes)

The first app I see in the list ("[chime](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/chime)") seems to be doing exactly what you describe, available on the iTunes App Store at [Chime](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chime/id414830146?mt=8)

Comment: Yes I was looking more about a trick using the build-in apple clock, but indeed the famous "there is an app for that" works as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Chime isn't available outside USA. ;-/ A lot of the others don't seem to work when in they are in the background. So, if someone has the perfect suggestion, it would be nice.

Comment: Why an app while you can use builtin tools? Rin Rio-Oki's answer below works perfectly using "Reminders" and setting up notifications for it.

Comment: @IamZesh you're kidding, right? It doesn't have an option for repeat hourly....the more I get into iPhone, the more I regret having moved from Android...iPhone stock apps are just rubbish!

Comment: @Jonathan Yes it does not have an option for this, but my point was only that you can achieve it without an app. The question iPhone vs Android is not the topic here.

Comment: @IamZesh Quoting your suggested answer: "Open the "Reminders" app and set up 24 reminder alerts" end quote...that's when I started laughing my arse off and couldn't continue reading... :-S

Comment: @Jonathan The answer I suggested answers the OP question(s), like the ones mentionning the apps do too. It's just a matter of preference. Glad that you had a nice laugh, by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

YES, you can setup an hourly chime on an iPhone WITHOUT downloading an app or any Jail Breaking for FREE!  With just using sounds already on your phone, or any custom tone you create. And you can further tweak it so it doesn't block or lock up your phone when you are being alerted of the passing hour.

OVERVIEW:

1) Using SIRI to set up a DAILY reminder that alerts you every hour and repeats INDEFINITELY.

2) Just alerts you of the passing hour with no other intrusive notifications.

3) Brain hack for the neurotic: Choosing a ringtone that is soothing or has a positive association.

4) Cons (that I ran into).

5) Taking your reminders further.

6) Positive feedback from you.

---Worked as of 03/15/2016.

---Version: iOS iPh5 9.2.1, iOS iPh4 7.1.2

---Tested on: iPh5 and two iPh4 Note: Siri does not work on iPh4, but linked devices automatically carry over information if spoken through the iPh5. I don't own a iPh6, but it should be the same.

---Time to finish: 'Bout 5-10mins.

You'll be doing this with Siri and the "Reminder" app, which comes FREE with the iPhone.

---

Let's Begin:

1) Hold down the center home button and say: 
"Remind me EVERYDAY when it's 12 O'clock A.M."

Siri will say: "OK, just tell me what you want to be reminded about."

(This is the title of the Reminder. Siri no longer gets caught up in a low A.I. logic loop. So, it can be anything you think of relevant or non-relevant.  So, mentioning the time twice will no longer trip up Siri, but it will make sense if the title name is meaningful to YOU, because you're about to add at least 24 new reminders where meaningful title names will make it easier to distinguish between a sea of other possible reminders.)

So, hypothetically, you COULD say:

- "Alert this Bitch everyday at 12 A.M." or;
- "Dude, tick-tock it's 12 o'clock or even non-sense like;
- "Stick and berries make the world go 'round."

The logistics no longer matter to Siri, BUT to make sense at some later point in the future for yourself, I would repeat the time, specify A.M. or P.M. and the occurrence.  Something like this:

"It's 12 A.M. again."

SIRI then will say: "OK, I'll start reminding you."

She'll show you:

- The newly created Reminder,
- Its creation date,
- The title name you choose for it,
- The time the reminder is set for,
- and the reminder's occurrence status.

You could review the Reminder's setup by tapping it, or manually close the screen, or do nothing and let the screen fade to black.

Repeat 23 more times.  Relax. Siri makes it a 5 min task!  At this point you're 99% done.

2) Now on to how Reminders will notify you.  Turn off all intrusive visual notifications of the reminder alert, which can interfere with you if you are driving with map directions, using your phone as night clock, scrolling through music, or just plain texting.

Open Settings> Notification Center> Reminders.

- Notification Sound: Choose your Apple sounds or import your own.
- Badge App Icon:  Toggled OFF.
- Show on Lock Screen:  Toggled OFF.
- ALERT STYLE WHEN UNLOCKED (Three images of iPhone alerts examples): Tap the "NONE" image.

This needs to be set only 1 time NOT 23 more times, because there's only one Reminder App.  We didn't magically create 24 or more.

ALL DONE!!

---

**Nutshell Review:**

- Hold down center the button to engage Siri.
- YOU SAY: "Remind me EVERYDAY when it's 12 O'clock A.M."
- Siri then will say: "OK, just tell me what you want to be reminded about."
- YOU SAY: "It's 12 A.M. again."
- Siri then will say: "OK, I'll start reminding you."
- Manually click-close your screen.

Repeat 23 more times.

Open Settings> Notification Center> Reminders.

- Notification Sound: Choose your Apple sounds or import your own.
- Badge App Icon:  Toggled OFF.
- Show on Lock Screen:  Toggled OFF.
- ALERT STYLE WHEN UNLOCKED (Three images of iPhone alerts examples): Tap the "NONE" image.

---

3) Using your own chime:  The psychological aspect behind choosing the right sound:

Try to begin to associate relaxing sounds with intense people and things, so if you get a text from your crazy mom, or your drama infused sister, choosing a non-toxic sound won't automatically place you on edge, or place you in a worrisome state of mind. You want to be open minded and level headed to deal with their nonsense.

Similar rational with choosing the right ringtone for your hourly chime. You don't want the sound to be intrusive when you're sleeping, and while awake you want the sound to always say this:

"One more hour of my life has just passed.  What positive thing have I done with this precious time?"

My soothing alert comes from Halle Berry's new Sci-fi Drama "Extant". This is the 21sec end theme I find amazingly relaxing: http://m.televisiontunes.com/Extant_-_Ending.html

4) The only CON I ran into so far is the assigning of different sounds to multiple reminders. Example: I really don't want my hour chime to be the same for a reminder to pick up some milk on the way home.

Untested work around You could also use the Calendar app and tweak the Notifications for it in settings...Hmmm.

5) Taking your reminders further. Did you notice location services in the tweak options. Imagine just having your alert go off only at work, or at the library. Or a reminder to take your trash out when you pass a street on a specific day on the way home from work.  So much potential.

6) Don't just hit and run.  If this worked, a few positive words would be great. Or post up and share a sound that's meaningful to you.  See ya!

Comment: Largest con I see is if you disable the reminders notifications on the lock screen, then when or if you ever use reminders normally, you can't.

Comment: So that's not a reminder that repeats every hour. That's 12 reminders.

Comment: My issue is that all these repeating reminders... pile up! I wish there were an automated garbage collection, i.e. deleting repeated reminders after X days. After all, what's the point in having 6000+ reminders marked as 'done'? Sure, I can delete them manually (and set a reminder for that!) but it's not my best choice...

Answer (score 1):

An app called [*Regularity ($0.99)*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/regularity/id505843608) should do the trick.

From their description:

> Want a quick & simple way of receiving regular, repeating alerts? Regularity makes this easy. It’s ideal for reminding you to:
>
> - Take medicine at certain times of the day, certain days of the week.
> - Make that call to someone special at the same time every day or week.
> - Back up the computer every month.
> - Renew your yearly insurance.

Note: I have no affiliation with this app developer or *Citrus Apps*. I know of the app because I used it in high school to notify me one minute before the bell rang so I wouldn't be caught by the bell.

Answer (score -2):

Try EveryHour app (https://itunes.apple.com/app/id963108472). Simple application for beeps

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with the app.