# How can I set hourly reminder in Mac? If possible how to set my customised voice?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, reminders

How can I set hourly reminder in Mac ? If possible how to set my customised voice?

Comment: Related in a way: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145808/how-to-make-your-iphone-beep-every-hour

Answer (score 13):

Open Date and Time Preferences.

[image]

Move to the <kbd>Clock</kbd> tab, and check Announce the time.

[image]

To customize the voice, click <kbd>Customize Voice</kbd>.

[image]

Choose one on the list, or click <kbd>Customize</kbd> for a larger list.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set up a reminder on Reminders, for example, set one for today at 9:00 am have it repeat daily. The trick is to never complete the reminder just click leave then select an hour this will give you a reminder with a note every hour.[image: Drink water]

Comment: hourly reminder *

Answer (score 2):

In the macOS (Big Sur 11.4) Reminders app create a new event like:

"My Reminder **every X hours**" and it will autocomplete with a "custom" value for the repeat setting once you click on the suggested time.
[image: macOS Reminders creating new event]

The even will then look like:
[image: macOS Reminders event with repeat every X hours]

Comment: I don't get this behaviour in macOS Catalina

Comment: @Darragh thanks for pointing that out. I added my macOS version (Big Sur 11.4) to the answer.

Comment: Maybe requires siri to be on? I do not get this suggestion in Big Sur 11.4

Comment: @KorayTugay just tried, works without Siri on my end. The moment my "Reminder" contains something like "every 2 hours" I see the suggestion dropdown.

Comment: Can't see this on Reminders Version 7.0 (2285)

Comment: @tir38 just checked in Version 7.0 (2515.10) and it works there for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I needed reminder notifications every X minutes; but did not want to use third-party app. I solved it using simple command which can be run on Mac Terminal:

```
while true; do osascript -e 'display notification "My notification message" with title "My reminder" sound name "My sound"'; sleep 60; done;
```

Just replace:

- `60` with desired time in seconds.
- `My sound` with sound names found in:

  - `~/Library/Sounds`
  - `/System/Library/Sounds`

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS Big Sur v11.4 go to System Preferences search with `Announce the time`

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Just told Siri to remind me to do something and it works!**

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).